# Sequel to novel Armor by John Steakley

Tags: john-steakley, armor-book

Does anyone know if the recently-deceased author of *Armor*, John Steakley, left behind any notes or outlines of a sequel? His unofficial [fan site](http://www.johnsteakley.com/) released a [teaser excerpt](http://johnsteakley.com/Armor2.html), but there's been no further information since his death this past November.

UPDATE: I added a significant bounty because this is one of my favorite books and I really, really, **really** want to know.

**Please give sources if you can.**

Comment: The Steakley fan site owner got back with me and pretty much confirmed the answer. Apparently, he had a basic plot outline that he only verbally shared with family members.

Comment: For anyone still looking for the Armor II excerpt, the johnsteakley.com site has been taken down. I dug up the archive though, and you can download the RTF [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120313015736/http://www.johnsteakley.com/Armor2.rtf)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the best source for information is the [Antwar Saloon](http://forums.johnsteakley.com/index.php), the forum on the site you linked.  The regulars there include some of Mr. Steakley's close friends, many of whom were at his funeral.  One actually was a speaker there.

The consensus there is that any unfinished works he has will not be published - they were not yet up to his exacting standards, and there is not sufficient demand for a Douglas Adams-style 'unfinished works' compendium.

Sad to say, whatever he had written is lost to the general public, at least until one of his books become a major blockbuster motion picture and demand sharply increases.

Comment: To more accurately respond to your initial question - yes, he did leave unfinished writings of a sequel, possibly including a plot summary.  Beyond the teaser, it's unlikely to be released.

Comment: I browsed the forums before and didn't see much, but I'll take another detailed look and see if it agrees with what you say. Seems like that will be not just the best, but ONLY source of info. I have also e-mailed the web site owner thanking him for keeping up with this little-known and way underrated author.

Comment: OK, looks like you're right... or close enough to get the points at least. That's quite a passionate group of fans... but I expected no less from such a great book. One post stated that over 300 pages of a sequel had been written, but a computer problem destroyed it... they even tried a professional data recovery service. Such a shame. I will let this question continue over the weekend, but I doubt anyone else will turn up anything different.

Comment: @Rodger: No problem :)  I figured it just would apply when the time ran out anyway.

Comment: He only wrote two books, but those two books are in my top five. If anyone were to work on _Armor 2_, it would be awesomesauce if it was John Scalzi, he of _Old Man's War_.

Comment: In a deleted answer below, they posted an excerpt from his unofficial fan-site: https://web.archive.org/web/20130917124428/http://johnsteakley.com/Armor2.html

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: Yes, we know.  That's the excerpt mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Jeff: Oh, you're right. Looks like the forum has since gone down.

Answer (score 2):

In 1996 I posted a review of *Armor* on a popular book selling site on the Internet. You might know it as a large retailer now; as large as a Brazilian river!  I was one of the first to review it.

To my surprise, John Steakley wrote back. I asked him about a sequel or prequel and told him I had some ideas of my own I would share with him. He said he had some ideas but had no plans to do a sequel at that time. He certainly didn't want to hear my ideas and now being older and wiser I understand why. I am sorry I didn't keep that email.

I love the book and just knowing that the world Felix knew is larger than we know has to be enough for now. I am sorry to hear he passed away before he could expand on the published world.

Maybe I'll buy and pass some copies of the book onto some people who may like it this Christmas. If enough of us do that maybe - just maybe - there will be a demand for that sequel if it does exist. We have to remember for Felix's sake.

Comment: I have edited your answer to remove some information that could personally identify you, as well as to improve grammar and formatting.  If you don't like it, feel free to roll back!